# How to convert from tuple to dictionary in python, for the following code?

Tags: python

({'timestamp': 1649767465, 'id': 48}, {'timestamp': 1649766359, 'id': 48}, {'timestamp': 1649766249, 'id': 48}, {'timestamp': 1649765101, 'id': 48}, {'timestamp': 1649747642, 'id': 48})

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: It should be a dictionary.

Comment: dict = {"timestamp" : 1649767465, "id" : 48 },{"timestamp" : 1649766359, "id" : 48 },{"timestamp" : 1649766249, "id" : 48 },{"timestamp" : 1649765101, "id" : 48 },{"timestamp" : 1649747642, "id" : 48 }

Comment: I need to call this dictionary with keywords and values.

Comment: I'm not following. Do you want a list of dictionaries? A dictionary of dictionaries doesn't exist (though you can use a frozenset).

Comment: That is not valid data representation for initializing a variable in Python. You can try entering that into a REPL and see that it throw an error and fails to initialize the variable `dict`.

Comment: A possible representation of the tuple of dictionaries would be a dictionary of tuples, e.g. something of the form `{'timestamps': (1649767465, 1649766359, ...), 'ids': (48, 48, ...)}`. Alternatively, you could try to group the timestamps under common ids, e.g. `{48: (1649767465, 1649766359, ...), 49: (..., )}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
({'timestamp': 1649767465, 'id': 48}, {'timestamp': 1649766359, 'id': 48}, {'timestamp': 1649766249, 'id': 48}, {'timestamp': 1649765101, 'id': 48}, {'timestamp': 1649747642, 'id': 48})
```

The above is a tuple of dictionaries. Lets take the first one i.e., `{'timestamp': 1649767465, 'id': 48}`, has two key value pairs. 
The tuple has no key to be made into a dictionary. Hence it will not be possible to make a nested dictionary in the above example. 
However, it could be converted into a list of dictionaries (if you want to update your variables later).

```
variable = [{'timestamp': 1649767465, 'id': 48}, {'timestamp': 1649766359, 'id': 48}, {'timestamp': 1649766249, 'id': 48}, {'timestamp': 1649765101, 'id': 48}, {'timestamp': 1649747642, 'id': 48}]
```

Now to get any element, just loop through the list and get the desired one. Every element is a dictionary hence the value can be called using key. 
For Example,

```
for v in variable:
   print(v['timestamp'])
   print(v['id'])
```

Output

```
1649767465
48
1649766359
48
1649766249
48
1649765101
48
1649747642
48
```